# NodeJs Update default credit card of customer for Stripe subscriptions and payment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am building an app in which i am using stripe to handle all payments. And in our app we have a common feature where user can update the default card for their subscriptions but it not working as expected. I Have followed the instruction to update the customer payment method as described in the stripe documentation but it's not working as expected i still see the old credit card details as default payment method in stripe dashboard.

Updating the customer:

```
 const customer = await stripe.customers.update(body.customerId, {
  invoice_settings: {default_payment_method: body.pId},
});
```

Attaching payment method to customer and updating subscription:

```
 const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(body.pId, {
  customer: body.customerId,
});

await stripe.subscriptions.update(subscriptionDetails?.planId as string, {
  default_payment_method: paymentMethod.id,
});
```

But still nothing, i am not sure what i am missing here but i couldn't update the default payment method.

[image: Stripe dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you shared refers to the payment methods saved on the Customer. If you wish to set the default payment method on the Customer, it will be under [`invoice_settings.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method) on Customer API.

Subscription's default payment method is different from Customer's default payment method. With [`default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-default_payment_method) on Subscription API, it will only update the default on the Subscription object, not Customer object like the page you see. You should be able to find Subscription's default payment method at the Subscription page.
[image]

Subscription page link will be: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/subscriptions/sub_xxx where `sub_xxx` is the Subscription ID.

Comment: but i am updating the both customer and subscription but still nothing updates in stripe

Comment: Do you use [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve) or [Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve) Retrieval API to check? If the payment method is created and set as default payment method successfully, it should be in Customer or Subscription object.